# How do I create 'n' blank pages

Tags: macros, blank-page

I need to insert a variable number (up to 40) of plain style pages into a document. Not inserting pdf's. 
I am aware of how to do this with a single page (see MWE) but is there a way to do it with 'n' number of pages, or do I just copy and paste lots of times?
I thought pdfpages might help somehow but as there are no file names I can't get it to work.

```
\documentclass[9pt,paper=a6,]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
Notes
\newpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
\mbox{}
\clearpage
Next Section
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for posting a MWE!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can put your "blank page recipe" into a loop, say using [pgffor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

```
\documentclass[9pt,paper=a6,]{scrbook}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand\InsertBlankPages[1]{% \InsertBlankPages{n} => insert n blank pages
  \foreach \blank in {1,...,#1} {
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \mbox{}
  }%
}

\begin{document}
  \InsertBlankPages{10}
\end{document}
```

Actually, the pages are not quite blank as they have a page number. If you want them truly blank then use `\thispagestyle{empty}`.

Answer (score 7):

The `expl3` function `\prg_replicate:nn` does what you want; its first argument is an integer *n* and the second argument is the code to be repeated *n* times.

```
\documentclass[9pt,paper=a6,]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\blankpages}{m}
 {
  \clearpage
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \mbox{}\thispagestyle{plain}\clearpage }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Notes

\blankpages{10}

Next Section

\end{document}
```